# Is it allowed for src and dest arguments of memcpy to overlap?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I need to shift contents of a byte buffer. Naturally, I started writing `memcpy`, but then realized it might have `restrict` specifier for the source and dest. My implementation (MSVC 2013) doesn't seem to have it. Cppreference lists two `memcpy` versions, with and without `restrict`, but I don't get it - I don't think these are overloads, and it's unclear to me how the compiler could correctly determine which one to pick.
On the other hand, the `memcpy` function could analyze the addresses and the `count` argument at runtime to determine if the address ranges overlap or not.

So, is it allowed to call `memcpy` with overlapping arguments? If not, is there any way to perform this operation that is better than plain `for`?

Comment: The documentation of `memcpy` is quite explicit isn't it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No [it is not](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), you should use [`memmove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html).

From [`memcpy(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html):

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas **must not overlap**.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.

From [`memmove(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html):

> The memmove() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas **may overlap**: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest.

The `restrict` keyword was added in the C99 standard, it is why [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) lists both versions (if you look carefully on the right, you can see `until C99` and `since C99`).

Answer (score 1):

The memory in memcpy cannot overlap or you risk undefined behaviour.

Use memmove instead.